# What condition in which a user application , or more detaily a process run as root in UNIX or SYSTEM in Windows

Tags: security, buffer, overflow

What condition in which a user application , or more detaily a process run as root in UNIX or SYSTEM in Windows, from that it might become target of buffer overflow attacks to run shellcode. I see on net, a simple C as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void func(char *name)
{
char buf[100];
strcpy(buf, name);
printf("Welcome %s\n", buf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
func(argv[1]);
return 0;
}
```

It can become premise for buffer overflow attack and running shellcode in Unix. I am focusing my question on program or process permission

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  I'm not clear what question you are asking.  The tags on your question probably aren't the best choice, either.  It looks as if C and maybe a tag such as [tag:buffer-overflow] or perhaps [tag:security] might be appropriate additions.  But you need to clarify what you're asking — as it stands, your question is not comprehensible and is, therefore, unanswerable.

Comment: i see on net the following  words:" In buffer overflow attacks,The exploit code will run with the program permissions. Because of this, exploiting an SUID root program is very useful since it will run with root privileges. On Unix systems, attackers normally target programs with UID 0 and in Windows, attackers normally target programs that run as SYSTEM."- infosecinstitute.com,  it originate my question

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few attack vectors when looking at privileged processes privileged processes. The first is the setuid bit, where a regular user invokes a setuid application and acquires the effective userid of the owner of the file. The next way that comes to mind is via Linux capabilities. Capabilities are like a more granular version of setuid, see `man getcap` for more information. One additional way is via network or IPC interfaces such UNIX sockets, named pipes, TCP or UDP sockets, etc) exposed by long-living processes (daemons)